# onResize event finishes before I lift one of the fingers

Tags: android, resize, gesture

I'm using following code to handle `resize(pinch)` event on android:

```
//my custom framelayout supporting resize functionality
ScalingFrameLayout pieceContainer=(ScalingFrameLayout)fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.pieceContainer);
//set onResize handler
setScaleListener(pieceContainer.getContext());
//tonnel touch events to gesture detector
pieceContainer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
...
//somewhere in the class
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
//
private void setScaleListener(Context context) {
mScaleDetector= new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d("onScaleEnd", "end");
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d("onScaleBegin", "begin");
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            Log.d("onScale", "zoom ongoing, scale: " + detector.getScaleFactor());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I do zoom-in gesture(for instance) this code calls `onScaleBegin`, then 5-6 times `onScale` and eventually it calls `onScaleEnd`. Although I didn't lift any of fingers from the screen.Is there way to prevent `ScaleGestureDetector` from calling `onScaleEnd` and to make it keep tracking my zoom gesture until I release the screen?

Comment: upd:further investigation revealed ScaleGestureDetector conflicts with HorizontalScrollView which is parent for my pieceContainer.I use two nested scrollviews since I need bidirectional scrolling.I wonder if there is native component for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by implementing custom bidirectional scrollview on base of frameLayout.